# Node.js http post multiple file

Tags: node.js

hello i'm trying to post multiple image in 1 request to webservice, but the value of array in webservice only the last. 
here are my code:

```
   var request = require('request');
              console.log(images.length);
              request.post(
                  {
                      url: path_api, 
                      formData: {
                          user_id : username,
                          room_id : room_id,
                          filename : files[0].name,
                          origin_file : fs.createReadStream(path_origin_image),
                          attachments:["rizal1","rizal2"],
                          api_key :process.env.AWP_API_KEY 
                      }
                   }, function(err, res, body) {
                      console.log(err);
                      console.log(body);
                      callback(err,res,body);

                  }
              );
```

and here are my output post in server, weird
[output server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHKio.jpg)
i want output like these
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeDHA.jpg)

thanks

Comment: Try assigning the attachment values in two lines `"attachment[0]":"rizal1", "attachment[1]":"rizal2"`

Comment: @idbehold thanks its working

Answer (score 0):

@idhehold thanks for the answer it works like a charm, here are the full solution

```
 var request = require('request');
          console.log(images.length);
          request.post(
              {
                  url: path_api, 
                  formData: {
                      user_id : username,
                      room_id : room_id,
                      filename : files[0].name,
                      origin_file : fs.createReadStream(path_origin_image),
                      "attachments[0]":"rizal1",
                      "attachments[1]":"rizal2",
                      api_key :process.env.AWP_API_KEY 
                  }
               }, function(err, res, body) {
                  console.log(err);
                  console.log(body);
                  callback(err,res,body);

              }
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a way to send files under the same form name (e.g. `files[]`) using request (that's how I ended up on this question), you can do this by modifying the `forms()` object before the next tick. This allows you to manipulate the multipart form data, and also allows duplicate keys.

```
let req = request(`/path/to/data`, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    formData: { }
}, (_err, resp, body) => {
    // handle the response
});

// the request actually gets sent at the next tick so we can still manipulate this
let form = req.form();
form.append('name', 'test');
form.append('files[]', Buffer.from('Hello world', 'utf-8'), {
    contentType: 'text/plain',
    filename: 'hello01.txt'
});
form.append('files[]', Buffer.from('Cheers', 'utf-8'), {
    contentType: 'text/plain',
    filename: 'world02.txt'
});
```

Note that I ran into issues calling this from an `async` function, modifying the function to be non-async worked.